# JavaFX8. Do I have to set the resource bundle for every FXMLLoader?

Tags: java, internationalization, javafx, javafx-8, resourcebundle

I have one large resource file for the whole application, so it would be nice if I could set it only ones for the whole JavaFX scene and not every time I do `new FXMLLoader(...)`.

Is there way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no mechanism to set a default resource bundle. You can always create a utility method to do this if you need:

```
public class MyUtils {

    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ... ;

    public static FXMLLoader getLoader(URL location) {
        return new FXMLLoader(location, bundle);
    }

}
```